# Assigning variable value inside recipe in GNUMakefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm not able to assign values to variable inside recipe.

```
debug: $(EXEC)
    CFLAGS+=-g -DDEBUG
    make $(EXEC) 
$(EXEC): example.c
   cc $(CFLAGS) -o example example.c
```

Output:

> ```
> CFLAGS+=-g -DDEBUG 
> /bin/sh: 1: CFLAGS+=-g: not found
> make: *** [debug] Error 127
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A make recipe is not makefile syntax, it's a shell script.  It's passed to the shell, which is a subprocess and (in UNIX/POSIX) there's no way for a subprocess to modify its parent.

There's a lot wrong here.  First, you should never use `make` to run make recursively, always use `$(MAKE)`.

Second, you have a useless recursion here.  `debug` depends on `$(EXEC)`, so *before* the debug recipe is run make will build `$(EXEC)`.  Then in the debug recipe you will recursively invoke make to build `$(EXEC)` again, but this will do nothing because `$(EXEC)` is already built.

You don't need the recursion, and you can use target-specific variables to do what you want:

```
debug: CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
debug: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): example.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```